# Qt QML - how to reverse geocode through mapbox plugin

Tags: qt, qml, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I've been trying to reversegeocode in QML by using the GeocodeModel QML type. I used the following code after creating the QML element.

```
geocodeModel.query = geoCoordinates // This is lat and lon coordinates
geocodeModel.update()
```

But im not getting the values in locationData property of it.
This is the GeocodeModel QML type

```
    GeocodeModel {
      id: geocodeModel
      plugin: map.plugin
      autoUpdate: false
    }
```

Anything that i should be adding?

Comment: What does `map.plugin.supportGeocoding(Plugin.ReverseGeocodingFeature)` returns ?

Comment: Its returning false

Comment: Then you can't reverse geocode with the mapbox plugin. It works with the OSM if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes, thanks,  its working with OSM and HERE maps, not with MAPBOXGL.  why is there a provider limitation?

Comment: Support for geocoding, reverse geocoding and place queries using Mapbox plugin landed in Qt 5.11: https://github.com/qt/qtlocation/commit/e5fab0a22988ed98657a4954b0104cc25213effc